# Asynchronous listview with cursor adapter

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-asynctask

I have a list view that shows data from a sqlite db. At first I used the typical code of getting a Cursor from a content provider query and then creating a SimpleCursorAdapter. The problem is that this database could get bigger and thus an asynchronous approach would be recommended.

I've read about CursorLoader and similar, but unfortunately my app needs to work on api level 4 so I can't use that.

Would there be some possible way to do this through an AsyncTask for example? Any help or snippet will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

CursorAdapter is the way to go.

If your database grows, you will run into usability issues (200 rows is too many rows to scroll through) well before you run into scalability issues.

Solve the UI issue through intelligent use of querying and filtering and you won't reach the performance issue.